# .gitlab-ci.yml Syntax Error

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab

I'm working with the following .gitlab-ci.yml config:

```
image: node:latest

stages: 
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install

 test:
   stage: test
   script:
     - ./testing/test.js
```

When pushing to GitLab, i get a 'Your pipeline as failed' error and when i look at what failed, its a yaml error:

```
Status: syntax is incorrect 

Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping 
at line 1 column 1
```

As far as i can see, the image: node:latest is correct. Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the indentation of you test job. That problem is making  your whole yml to break therefore raising the error on line 1. Just remove the excessive whitespaces like the code below and it will be fine.

```
image: node:latest

stages: 
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install

test:
 stage: test
 script:
   - ./testing/test.js
```

**Note that in *YAML* the indentation is used to denote the structure. So it is important to pay attention to it.**

Comment: Oh dear god! What an overlook by me. Thanks for correcting that :). Problem solved.

Comment: Yaml is weird. Even so, better diagnostics might have helped. (Anyway, thanks for this; I just had the same inexplicable problem.)